# How to search a file that has space delimiters and add it to an array or arraylist java?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to add strings from a file that contains states and capitals to two arraylists. My problem is that some states/capitals have two words of which i want in one element. 
This is what my file looks like

```
California          Sacramento
New Hampshire       Concord
```

and I want the arraylist to look like this

```
states[0]  - California

capitals[0] Sacramento

states[1] New Hampshire

capitals[1] Concord
```

but it breaks up two word states or capitals which i dont want

```
states[1] = New

states[2] = Hampshire
```

here is my code

```
public class InputOutput 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

    ArrayList<String> states = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> capitals = new ArrayList();
    File f = new File("US_states.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
    while(input.hasNextLine());
    {
        states.add(input.next());
        capitals.add(input.next());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to use something different than a space for a delimiter.  Otherwise, there is no way to differentiate between a space in a state name/city name and a delimiter.

Comment: @MichaelKrause You can't really say there is "no" way to differentiate, i mean you could spend time differentiating between the two in your application, it just wouldn't be very feasible.

Comment: You could see if the state is North, South, West, New, or Rhode (I think that covers all of them) and if it is concat it with the next word. Like Michael said, there's no way to do this purely programatically (ie independent of state/capital name) since you're using spaces to dictate when to change.

Comment: You should update your question. As is, it appears you already know how to search a file that has space delimiters and add results to an array.

Comment: @Jlas But it doesn't cover the capitals, there you'll also have Little, Des, Baton, St., Jefferson, Carson, Santa, Oklahoma, and Salt + Lake. In short: enough to be impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from `java.util.Scanner` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

Your `Scanner` has no predefined delimiter, and as such tokenizes on whitespace.

It is very hard for you to set a contextual delimiter without teaching your program in advance that the space between `New` and `Hampshire` is not the same as the space between `California` and `Sacramento`.

If you have control over the text file, consider setting a specific delimiter between state and capital, then set it in your `Scanner`.

Otherwise you're likely to be stuck.